# Sending Mail Using Gmail In Codeigniter

Tags: php, email, gmail, cpanel, codeigniter-3

I will try to send mail using gmail in codeigniter. I write code as given bellow. When i upload it on c panel it will work properly for 2 days but after that it stop working.

```
//Load email library
$this->load->library('email');

//SMTP & mail configuration
$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxxxxx',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxx',
    'mailtype'  => 'html',
    'charset'   => 'utf-8'
);
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->set_mailtype('html');
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

//Email content
$htmlContent = '<h1>MY WEBSITE</h1>';
$htmlContent .= '<p>OTP For Reset Your Password.</p>';

$this->email->to($uemail);
$this->email->from('xxxxxxxx','MyWebsite');
$this->email->subject('MESSAGE');
$this->email->message($htmlContent);

//Send email
$this->email->send();
```

Comment: is it showing any errors?

Comment: No there is no any error.

Comment: What determines if a mail is being sent? Is it a cron job, on user action etcetera :-)

Comment: for forget password button click

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing where the email was not sent and there was no error, it turned out that when I checked my Gmail account it wasn't always on the **Primary** tab (make sure it wasn't in the **Spam** folder either). Sent but in the **Promotions** tab.

[image]